# HTML/PHP input file does not pass photos taken on the spot (mobile)

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a strange problem with file input. More precisely image input. The problem is this: if I input an image uploaded from the gallery, everything is fine. The moment I input an image taken on the spot (on mobile you have the option to take a picture and not choose it from the gallery) and submit the form, I get an error. I have set up various error messages and the one I get is:  `"NO FILE UPLOADED VIA HTTP POST"` . But the form is set to POST. What could the problem be?

Comment: my guess is you're not adding the image to the form / FormData, need to provide code to be sure.

Comment: but if the image is taken from the gallery it works perfectly. So the image is added to the form...